# java.io.EOFException when adding MQMessage to TextArea

Tags: java, textarea, ibm-mq

I am reading a reply message from Websphere MQ.
Reading the message is not a problem. The problem comes in when I want to add the content of the message to a textArea but I am getting an exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: MQJE086: End of file exception ('MQMessage.readString()').
    at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.readStringOfByteLength(MQMessage.java:1204)
    at mq.MqWriter.doInBackground(MqWriter.java:294)
    at mq.MqWriter.doInBackground(MqWriter.java:1)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my code where I want to add the content of the MQMessaget to the TextArea:

```
panelMq.getPanelMqOutput().getTxtaMqOutput().
setText(replyGetMQMessage.readStringOfByteLength(replyGetMQMessage.getMessageLength()));
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

readstringofByteLength reads the number of supplied *bytes* from the message, and converts to a (Unicode) String. You must be getting EOF as the number of bytes you pass in as the parameter are not remaining from the position in the message where the read starts from.